# Validate variable javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I need to validate some user input with javascript. I need to check that their entry (value) is of the correct type (type).

I need my regex pattern to make sure values only contain numbers and nothing else, except measurment types can also contain decimal points.

What is the correct way to do this? My way seems like it may be, but i am guessing. In any case, something is wrong with my regular expression patterns as it is throwing the error stated in the code comment.

Here is my code:

```
    function validateInput(value, type) {
console.log(value);
if(type === "Integer"){
    var patt = new RegExp("^\D", i);
}
else if(type === "Measurement"){
    var patt = new RegExp("^\D", i); //Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor '2' 
}
else{
    return true;
}


if(patt.test(value)){
    return false;
}
else{
    return true;
}
}




function sendObs() {
    RID = $("#oid").val();
    console.log(RID);
    var children = $("#abc").children();
    var xmlString = "<root><rid>" + RID + "</rid>";

    for(i=0; i < children.length; i++){
        var value = children[i].children[0].value;
        var type = children[i].children[0].id;
        var validationResult = validateInput(value, type);
        if(!validationResult){                //calling the validation method here
            alert("invalid entry");
            return;
        }
        var code = children[i].children[0].className;
        xmlString += '<question><code>' + code + '</code><value>' + value + '</value></question>'
    }
    xmlString +='</root>'
    console.log(xmlString);
    data = $.parseXML(xmlString);
    console.log(data);

    //send it here

}
```

Comment: your missing quotes in your regex declaration  `new RegExp([a-z], i);` ==> `new RegExp("[a-z]", i);`

Comment: Apart from the missing quotes: you are only checking a single character. Use `patt = new RegExp(/^[0-9]+$/);` to test an entire string. (Better yet: `patt = new RegExp(/^\d+$/)`.)

Comment: @Jongware Cheers. I don't see some of those characters in the W3Schools tutorial. What is "/" doing? Also "$/"?

Comment: That's why [W3Schools has a bad reputation](http://www.w3fools.com/). [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is a better document.

Comment: Apologies, I see now [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) that indeed a `new RegExp` needs `"`, not `/`, around the expression.

Comment: @Jongware Thank you, I will study your suggested web page now. I have also updated my question, as I got my requirement slightly wrong in my initial question.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: @meagar Apologies. Have update question. I got a little confused with my regex checks too. Basically need my regex pattern to make sure they only contain numbers and nothing else, except measurment types can also contain decimal points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using regular expressions, you could just call `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()`.

On top of converting your strings to workable numbers, both functions return `NaN` if the input is invalid.

```
number = parseFloat(string)

if (isNaN(number)) {
    # `string` is invalid 
}
```